# Aptana 3 on raspberry pi 3 doesn't work ? both 32bit and 64bit version

Tags: raspberry-pi, aptana, aptana3

I've been using nano editor most of the time to work on some php jquery projects that while I found nano is good, I need to find a better full blown IDE as the work load increases. Anyway Aptana3 studio looks like a good fit and I go download it into my raspberry pi 3

I tried 32bit and 64bit version, but both gave me same error when I execute the binary :

```
bash: ./AptanaStudio3: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading a pre-built binary for Linux running on Intel. If it were available, you'd want to get a pre-built binary for ARM. In looking at the Aptana download site I don't see an ARM version.

Comment: thanks for your answer, @vielmetti. yeah, unfortunately they don't have ARM version of this otherwise nice IDE yet